# Calling a bootstrap modal from an Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to replace an alert for a bootstrap modal in the Angular controller that produces the successful sent mail. (The actual mail sending meat and potatoes is done with PHPMailer)

So, this is my controller:

```
// create angular controller
app.controller('form', function($scope) {

    // function to submit the form after all validation has occurred            
    $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {

        // check to make sure the form is completely valid
        if (isValid) {      
           alert('our form is amazing');
        }

    };
});
```

I want to change that call from `alert('our form...')` to `<div class="modal fade in" class="".....</div>`

Now here is the other part I am confused on. I imagine the should be a way to "store" the modal in something that can be called from the controller without having to put the entire modal html in there, am I right? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: most would use `angular-ui-bootstrap` and get rid of `bootstrap.js`

Comment: I am using it! Care to illuminate me on this direction? :)

Comment: follow example in docs ... js and html code is shown as well as plunker demo links

Comment: I checked it out and I understand how it is used from an html document but not from inside a controller which it's my question. No examples provided.

Comment: inject `$uibModal` and use `open()` in your function

Comment: It conflicts with my angular validations. Is there way to do a simple boostrap modal? I'm not using modals anywhere so I'm ok with a simple solution

Comment: Was wondering why you wanted a modal inside a submit function. Not clear what you are trying to do to be honest

Comment: lol. ok. I'll explain better. I have a contact form built with angular validations. The validations control the form from the front end so that the users put valid information or they won't be able to click on the button. Once that is all satisfied, the button triggers 2 events. One is coded in PHPMailer to send the information to the server and to the email. That is all coded successfully in the mail.php file executed from the form `action=""`

Comment: The second event on that click of the button happens at the app.js file where my controller is (the one I put in the question). This controller verifies the information is valid and puts out an alert that says "our form is awesome" . Well, I don't like alerts, I'd rather it would a modal instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add modal to your view and then call it by id:

```
<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade in" class="".....</div>
```

..

```
// create angular controller
app.controller('form', function($scope) {

    // function to submit the form after all validation has occurred            
    $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {

        // check to make sure the form is completely valid
        if (isValid) {      
           angular.element(myModal1).modal("show");
        }

    };
});
```

Comment: Done! Good job! Thank you!

Comment: @Slava N. - Could you please take a look at this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xesgxe I am unable to call a bootstrap modal from a function. If I click on the link in the app it works but when I click on `input`, the modal doesn't pop.

Answer (score 2):

For angular environment, you should use Ui-Bootstrap modal service.

Try to bind the codes in Factory to reuse it through out your app. Just inject $uibModal in your controller/factory.

Sample code below to confirm delete with Bootstrap modal service:

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: true,
    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
    controller: function($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
        $scope.customBody = 'Are you sure to delete?';
        $scope.ok = function() {
            $uibModalInstance.close();
            var _res = DataFactory.deleteData(DataId);
            _res.then(function(data) {
                if (data == 1) {
                    UiFactory.alerts.success('Data deleted successfully!');
                    $rootScope.DataList.splice(index, 1);
                } else {
                    UiFactory.alerts.error('Operation failed! Please try again');
                }
            }, function(error) {
                console.log('Error = ' + error);
            });
        };
        $scope.cancel = function() {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    },
    size: 'sm'
});
```

Comment: This is a good solution +1 except it conflicts with the validation when I inject $uibModal. But it would work otherwise