# Implementing bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to adapt the following Fiddle:
[Bootstrap modal](http://jsfiddle.net/jasny/zclse/)

Here is my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/jasny-bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/jasny-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<style>
    .modal-body {
        max-height: calc(100vh - 150px);
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
</style>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel vehicula erat. Phasellus vestibulum leo eu mi tempor blandit. Suspendisse eget iaculis lectus. Donec vitae tempus enim, quis tristique magna. Donec lobortis, sem ac pretium viverra, leo nisl consequat arcu, sit amet ullamcorper nunc turpis ac erat. In rutrum auctor ligula, quis mattis enim lacinia eu. Aliquam at magna a erat laoreet iaculis quis a justo. Donec porttitor vulputate massa, nec suscipit nisi mollis sed.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

When I run it I see the blue button, but when I click on it nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Why do your html block not wrapped with <body> tag? Only <head>, than <style> and then <div>. It should be <head>...styles</head><body>your html </body>. And at the end </html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't load jQuery above the bootstrap js. Now use this.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now it will be working.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/jasny-bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/jasny-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<style>
    .modal-body {
        max-height: calc(100vh - 150px);
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
</style>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel vehicula erat. Phasellus vestibulum leo eu mi tempor blandit. Suspendisse eget iaculis lectus. Donec vitae tempus enim, quis tristique magna. Donec lobortis, sem ac pretium viverra, leo nisl consequat arcu, sit amet ullamcorper nunc turpis ac erat. In rutrum auctor ligula, quis mattis enim lacinia eu. Aliquam at magna a erat laoreet iaculis quis a justo. Donec porttitor vulputate massa, nec suscipit nisi mollis sed.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Yep, you are correct. But I did not see it in the Fiddle.

Comment: Did you check the `External Resources` section in the Fiddle ?

Comment: Now, when it runs for me how would I run this modal popup in Angular environment? Situation when a trigger button is on one page but the popup itself is a different template?

Comment: Actually I don't have much knowledge about Angular JS. You can see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677786/calling-a-bootstrap-modal-from-an-angular-controller/35679421